# State not getting updated in redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

i am trying to generate an array of movies which is working correctly and the "result" which is being consoled has the genres id[image: Here is the consoled data in result]
and the getGenres function has all the genres with id [image: Genres data]
why is genres empty in when movies array is being created.

```
export const getGenres = createAsyncThunk("netflix/genres", async () => {
  const {
    data: { genres },
  } = await axios.get(`${TMBD_BASE_URL}/genre/movie/list?api_key=${API_KEY}`);
  console.log(genres);
  return genres;
});
```

```
const netflixSlice = createSlice({
  name: "netflix",
  initialState,
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addCase(getGenres.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
      state.genres = action.payload;
      state.genresLoaded = true;
    });
    builder.addCase(fetchMovies.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
      state.movies = action.payload;
    });
  },
});
```

```
export const fetchMovies = createAsyncThunk(
  "netflix/trending",
  async ({ type }, thunkAPI) => {
    const {
      netflix: { genres },
    } = thunkAPI.getState();
    return rawData(
      `${TMBD_BASE_URL}/trending/${type}/week?api_key=${API_KEY}`,
      genres,
      true
    );
  }
);
```

```
const rawData = async (api, genres, paging = false) => {
  const moviesArray = [];
  for (let i = 1; moviesArray.length < 60 && i < 10; i++) {
    try {
      const {
        data: { results },
      } = await axios.get(`${api}${paging ? `&page=${i}` : ""}`);

      createArrayfromRawdata(results, moviesArray, genres);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }

  return moviesArray;
};
```

```
const createArrayfromRawdata = (array, moviesArray, genres) => {
  array.forEach((movie) => {
    const movieGenres = [];
    movie.genre_ids.forEach((genre) => {
      const name = genres.find(({ id }) => id === genre);
      if (name) movieGenres.push(name.name);
    });
    if (movie.backdrop_path)
      moviesArray.push({
        id: movie.id,
        name: movie?.original_name ? movie.original_name : movie.original_title,
        image: movie.backdrop_path,
        genres: movieGenres.slice(0, 3),
      });
  });
};
```

I am trying to get the genres according to the movie data and which matches the id of the genres.

Comment: It is likely that the genres array is empty because the `genres` variable in the `getGenres` function is not being populated correctly. The `axios.get` call is not returning the expected data, or it is not being handled correctly. Check the response data from the API and make sure it is being handled correctly in the `getGenres` function.

Answer (score 0):

My guess here is that you are dispatching both `getGenres` and `fetchMovies` at the same time and not waiting for one to complete before starting the other. Perhaps something like the following:

```js
const fetchMoviesData = (type) => {
  dispatch(getGenres());
  dispatch(fetchMovies({ type });
};
```

The problem with this is that the genres state might not have been populated yet, or at all, when trying to fetch the movies.

One way to address this is to wait for the genres action to have completed and the state updated.

Example:

```js
const fetchMoviesData = async (type) => {
  try {
    await dispatch(getGenres()).unwrap();
    // Getting genres success, not get movies
    dispatch(fetchMovies({ type });
  } catch(error) {
    // catch and handle/ignore
  }
};
```

Since there's a dependency on `state.netflix.genres` to fetch the movies, incorporate the genres fetching directly within the `fetchMovies` action.

Example:

```js
export const fetchMovies = createAsyncThunk(
  "netflix/trending",
  async ({ type }, thunkApi) => {
    try {
      // Fetch genres if not loaded yet
      if (!thunkApi.getState().netflix.genresLoaded) {
        await thunkApi.dispatch(getGenres());
      }

      const { genres } = thunkApi.getState().netflix;

      return rawData(
        `${TMBD_BASE_URL}/trending/${type}/week?api_key=${API_KEY}`,
        genres,
        true
      );
    } catch(error) {
      return thunkApi.rejectWithValue(error);
    }
  }
);
```

```js
const fetchMoviesData = (type) => {
  dispatch(fetchMovies({ type });
};
```